# October CMS - Range field type or custom in Create / Update form

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I need to set an input range on a form to create and update. In the October CMS documentation, I found a list solution, but in the register there is no "range" field.

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1">
```

I'm using the "Builder Plugin".The closest thing to the solution was the "macros" feature, but the documentation about the feature didn't help much. Has anyone found a solution for creating their own input types or range?

Answer (score 3):

October CMS is very extendable platform. You can extend each and every aspect of it.

Same goes for builder plugin you can extend it as per your needs.

Please hold on this answer will be long but You will find it lot of useful.

### Final Results

> 1. It will add control to control list so you can easily add it and reuse it for other fields as well.

[image]

> 2. Configurable - you don't need to edit any file/partial to change its values. its all inside builder plugin. your values [min, max, step] field-name etc.. all you can edit/update from builder plugin.

[image]

> 3. Its automatic. means labels and field-name all will work like other controls you don't need to specify anything else. all will be dynamic.

[image]

### So lets start extending builder plugin :)

> 1. add this code to your plugin boot method `plugin.php`, it will basically add the control to builder plugin control list. [1st image]

```php
public function boot() {

  \Backend\Widgets\Form::extend(function($widget) {
    $widget->addViewPath(\File::symbolizePath('~/plugins/hardiksatasiya/sotest/classes/CustomDesignTimeProvider/field_partials'));
  });

  \Event::listen('pages.builder.registerControls', function($controlLibrary) {
    $properties = [
      'min' => [
        'title' => 'Min',
        'type' => 'string',
        'default' => '0',
        'ignoreIfEmpty' => false,
        'sortOrder' => 81
      ],
      'max' => [
        'title' => 'Max',
        'type' => 'string',
        'default' => '100',
        'ignoreIfEmpty' => false,
        'sortOrder' => 82
      ],
      'step' => [
        'title' => 'Step',
        'type' => 'string',
        'default' => '10',
        'ignoreIfEmpty' => false,
        'sortOrder' => 83,
      ]
    ];

    $controlLibrary->registerControl(
      'my_range',
      'Range Field',
      'Custom Range Field',
      \RainLab\Builder\Classes\ControlLibrary::GROUP_STANDARD,
      'icon-arrows-h',
      $controlLibrary->getStandardProperties(['stretch'], $properties),
      \HardikSatasiya\SoTest\Classes\CustomDesignTimeProvider::class
    );
  });

.... your extra code ...
```

> 2. now you need to create/add required dependent files `plugins/hardiksatasiya/sotest/classes/CustomDesignTimeProvider.php` , `plugins/hardiksatasiya/sotest/classes/CustomDesignTimeProvider/partials/_control-my_range.htm` and `plugins/hardiksatasiya/sotest/classes/CustomDesignTimeProvider/field_partials/_field_my_range.htm'`

### plugins/hardiksatasiya/sotest/classes/CustomDesignTimeProvider.php

```php
<?php namespace HardikSatasiya\SoTest\Classes;

use File;
use RainLab\Builder\Classes\ControlDesignTimeProviderBase;

class CustomDesignTimeProvider extends ControlDesignTimeProviderBase {

    public function renderControlBody($type, $properties, $formBuilder)
    {
        return $this->makePartial('control-'.$type, [
            'properties'=>$properties,
            'formBuilder' => $formBuilder
        ]);
    }

    public function renderControlStaticBody($type, $properties, $controlConfiguration, $formBuilder)
    {
        $partialName = 'control-static-'.$type;
        $partialPath = $this->getViewPath('_'.$partialName.'.htm');
        if (!File::exists($partialPath)) {
            return null;
        }
        return $this->makePartial($partialName, [
            'properties'=>$properties,
            'controlConfiguration' => $controlConfiguration,
            'formBuilder' => $formBuilder
        ]);
    }
   
    public function controlHasLabels($type)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

### plugins/hardiksatasiya/sotest/classes/CustomDesignTimeProvider/partials/_control-my_range.htm

```html
<div class="builder-blueprint-control-text">
    <i class="icon-arrows-h"></i> Range Field
</div>
```

> 3. while above steps will add our custom control to the plugin builder list, next step will be adding form field partial. [3rd image]

### plugins/hardiksatasiya/sotest/classes/CustomDesignTimeProvider/field_partials/_field_my_range.htm

```html
<!-- Range -->
<?php if ($this->previewMode): ?>
    <span class="form-control"><?= $field->value ? e($field->value) : '&nbsp;' ?></span>
<?php else: ?>
    <div  style="display: flex;">
        <span style="width: 30px; margin-right: 20px;" id="<?= $field->getId() ?>_val">
            <?= $field->value ?>
        </span>
        <span>
           [<?= $field->getConfig('min') ?>]
        </span>
        <input
            type="range"
            name="<?= $field->getName() ?>"
            id="<?= $field->getId() ?>"
            value="<?= e($field->value) ?>"
            min="<?= $field->getConfig('min') ?>"
            max="<?= $field->getConfig('max') ?>"
            step="<?= $field->getConfig('step') ?>"
            oninput="(function(input) { document.getElementById('<?= $field->getId() ?>_val').innerText = input.value;  })(this)"
            <?= $field->getAttributes() ?>
        />
        <span>
            [<?= $field->getConfig('max') ?>]
        </span>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

This html files are just html markup so can edit them and add css/style according to your need.

Once you did following steps you will able to see your `custom range control` in form builder's control list. now you can add it update it just like any other default control.

Its fully dynamic you can choose `field-name, min, max, step` and it will be applied.

> Note: **Just make sure you replace `author-name` and `plugin-name` according to your setup in provided code.**

if you have any doubts please comment.

Answer (score -1):

Well this was unique and after some research and testing I came up with a way to do this. I will remark that there isn't any reason that I have personally found to justify a range slider in a form. So I understand why OctoberCMS doesn't have one natively.

1. Inside the builder plugin you need to add the input field of the value you want to be stored and change the setting to be read only.

[image: Photo showing the field's options.]

2. Inside the builder plugin you will want to add a partial. I called my partial `something.htm` for testing purposes. The whole path to the partial is: `$/dle/test/models/products/something.htm` Note the $ is just to evoke the starting point of the search.

[image]

3. Not inside the `something.htm` partial I have this: The `label` and `input` of the range. Natively the `range` element doesn't show the amount but with javascript and jquery we can connect this range to the price field.

   ```
   <label for="priceRange">Price Range</label> 
   <input id="priceRange" type="range" min="0" max="10" step=".25" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);">
   ```
4. Now you have to go to your `create.htm` and `update.htm` pages under controller. IE: `author/plugin/controllers/controller/create.htm`. Here I have entered the javascript / jquery to connect the range to the input field.

   ```
   <script>
   function updateTextInput(val) {
     document.getElementById('Form-field-Products-price').value=val; 
   }

   var value = $('#Form-field-Products-price').val();

   $('#priceRange').val(value);
   </script>
   ```

[image]