# How to create custom data type with custom form

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, october-form-controller

I recently started working with October CMS.
I found on the Internet a kind of solution to my problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019789/october-cms-range-field-type-or-custom-in-create-update-form/58038711#58038711)
But I did not understand how I can adapt the solution to my own

My form is actually a Mapbox map in which the user draws polygons, adds any information to the polygon, such as the color of the polygon and a description. Before saving, I perform a few operations on the polygons.

Something like: p_id: [choised from select], polygons_json: [0:[geo],1:[geo],2:[geo]], descriptions_json: [0:[desc],1:[desc],2:[desc]] .

I noticed that for this they use hidden fields in which data is saved. I was also puzzled by the use of JS

I used the Builder plugin and edited it manually,